# IIS returns 302 when not on local host

Tags: iis, asp.net, redirect

I am working on an asp.net page that handles paypal IPNs (instant payment notification).

For those who don't know how IPNs work, I'll explain. When some kind of transaction occurs on paypals servers, paypal will send a POST message back to a certain page on my server. If customer A uses paypal, paypal lets us know so we can keep records of transactions that don't actually occur on our machines.

My box has proper port forwarding. Paypay sends data to http://www.companyurl.com:2343/ProcessPaypal.ashx, where port 2343 redirects to my box running IIS. This set up was working fine yesterday. Today, however, I stopped getting any of my test IPNs.

Running wireshark, it looks like my box is receiving those IPNs, but returning 302s that look like this: http://www.companyurl.com/ProcessPaypal.ashx (notice the lack of a port number).

My question is this: is there a way to tell my computer not to 302 the IPNs and just process them like it should? As far as I know I didn't change any config files. Also, I can access these pages fine on local host.

Answer (score 0):

if you were developing on that box, you may have left a debug session open. We had this exact issue about a week ago.

Comment: Yes I have been developing on this box.  I've restarted the box once already though.  If there was an open debug session I'm fairly sure that would have killed it.  Unless you know something that I don't.

Comment: Sorry, that's all I got. A reboot would clear the debug sessions, so that's probably not it then.

Comment: Bummer.  Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: Hi @CountMurphy. Did you figure out what the issue is? I am facing a similar issue. I cant open only the register.asp page in my domain. I see a 302 document/redirect in network log. I am also connecting to the azure server via RDP and working on the file directly. here is  my question in my other new account => https://serverfault.com/questions/1153416/error-when-accessing-particular-page-of-an-asp-application