# error when accessing particular page of an asp application

Tags: azure, windows-server-2022, asp-classic, netscaler

Recently few asp applications got migrated to Azure windows server with IIS 10. I have fixed most of the post-migration issues except one.

When I open this page https://abc.xyz.com/login/register.asp this page auto redirects to the root https://abc.xyz.com then displays the 403 forbidden error by default config.

I don't understand why this page wont open and keeps redirecting.

here are the list of items I have tried so far.

1. Checked for URL rewrite rules if any - found nothing
2. Checked for IIS logs - found no register.asp URL first. But after few tries I see this line =>

2024-02-12 09:14:46 192.168.xxx.xxx GET /register.php - 443 - 192.168.xxx.xxx Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/121.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 - 404 0 2 1617

3. ensured app pool configuration for asp is correct - correct and asp is working.
4. deleted and recreated the website - no help
5. cleared cache or run in incognito - not resolved
6. configured failed request tracing - no capture
7. checked for server errors and custom redirects - nothing found. the page doesnt run at all.
8. found nothing visible so far in the firewall rules
9. Also checked the ip/domain restrictions - no restrictions

Similar issues from the internet tell the error is related to the SSL certification.

note: This is a subdomain where I am facing this issue. I cant figure out what is the issue. Kindly guide me. Thanks.

---

**Update 20 Feb:**
It was because of the Web App Firewall Signatures on NetScaler. Setting all to disable and only enable all signatures for “web-iis” fixed the issue.
[Find the screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQulr.png)

Comment: Why didn't you put them in an Azure Web App? Could have saved you a server. And is the proper feature installed `Get-WindowsFeature Web-Asp-Net45`

Comment: @Turdie - The issue is resolved. Updated in the question itself. Thanks for your interaction.